# Connecting to multiple namespace with spring cloud vault

Tags: spring-cloud-vault-config

Spring cloud vault enables connecting to a namespace with property "spring.cloud.vault.namespace". I have an use-case to read secrets stored in different namespaces. Is this possible with sprint cloud vault? or there any other approaches?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The namespace is configured through the client by registering a `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` in `RestTemplate` respective `ExchangeFilterFunction` in `WebClient`.

This approach serves the purpose of allowing client authentications to authenticate against the appropriate namespace without making each authentication mechanism aware of its namespace. Later on, `VaultTemplate` is configured with the namespaced client to avoid downstream namespace configuration in the `VaultTemplate`.

If you need to use multiple namespaces, then ideally configure individual `SessionManager` and `VaultTemplate` objects per namespace.

Depending on your authentication mechanism (i.e. if you use tokens instead of login methods) there are other possible approaches. One could consist of a single `SessionManager`/`VaultTemplate` where you store the namespace and token in a `ThreadLocal` and provide a `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` for a single `VaultTemplate` that communicates with the desired namespace.